# how to do a GET request using retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, spring-security, restful-authentication

I have a restfull web service which is running on a localhost. I would like to make a retrofit2 GET request on that rest URL.

**MainActivity.java**

```
private void requestData() {
        public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.103:8080/SpringWithHibernate/users/";
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "In requestData() :: " + "ddd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        GetUserListAPI api = retrofit.create(GetUserListAPI.class);

        api.getUsersList().enqueue(new Callback<List<UserPojo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<UserPojo>> call, Response<List<UserPojo>> response) {
                Log.d("UserList :: ", "Success");
                Log.d("UserList :: ", "Code :: " + response.code());

                user = response.body();

//                Log.d("UserList :: ", "count :: " + user.size());

//                Log.d("UserList :: ", "Result :: " + user.get(1).getUsername());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<UserPojo>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("UserList :: ", "Failure");
            }
        });

    }
```

**GetUserListAPI.java** interface:

```
public interface GetUserListAPI {
    @GET("/users")
    Call<List<UserPojo>> getUsersList();
}
```

When I make a call to requestData() method I keep getting response.code() as 404.

Can anyone help me where should I have mistaken?

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Can you use this url and check response -> http://demo1874861.mockable.io/

Comment: make String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.103:8080/SpringWithHibernate/"   means without "users/" in BASE_URL

Comment: and use in interface method like this `@GET("users")
    Call<List<UserPojo>> getUsersList();`

Comment: Yes,.. by removing / from the interface @GET("users") is worked for me. Thanks to all who is under this conversation.

Answer (score 3):

Your baseurl contains /users in the end.It should be removed as it will be received by the app from the inerface  @GET("/users")
Your baseUrl should be

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.103:8080/SpringWithHibernate/"
```

and in interface

```
public interface GetUserListAPI {
    @GET("users")
    Call<List<UserPojo>> getUsersList();
}
```

Comment: remove / ,add / before user in the interface as i have written above

Comment: you add at the end of BaseUrl `http://192.168.0.103:8080/SpringWithHibernate/` and use like this in interface .... `@GET("users")`

Comment: yes,the main part here was not to repeat users. You are also right

Comment: Yes,.. by removing / from the interface @GET("users") is worked for me. Thanks to all who is under this conversation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 404 error its not associated with the retrofit, its backend issue. Is that webservice is currently active one?
But i found another issue in your request, which is that

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.103:8080/SpringWithHibernate/users/";
```

and in Retrofit interface you have declared

```
@GET("/users")
```

So the combined URL will result in

```
http://192.168.0.103:8080/SpringWithHibernate/users/users
```

Which is not correct, you should only declare your base url in the string and service names in retrofit interface methods.

Comment: Yes,.. by removing / from the interface @GET("users") is worked for me. Thanks to all who is under this conversation.