# Get request in retrofit generates 500 internal server error

Tags: android, retrofit

I have integrated retrofit 2.0 with android app. The postman response works fine for the API, when I integrate it with android app,  it generates internal server error

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Call<List<Result>> results = RetroClient.getApiService().getResponse("application/json");

        results.enqueue(new Callback<List<Result>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Result>> call, Response<List<Result>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            String.valueOf(response.message()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "ifferror", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Result>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

RetroClient.java

```
public class RetroClient {

    private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://azeemkhan.me/quflip/api/rest/";


    private static Retrofit restAdapter;
    private static ApiService apiService;

    static {
        setupRestClient();
    }

    private static void setupRestClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build();
        restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }


    public static ApiService getApiService() {
        if (apiService == null) {
            apiService = restAdapter.create(ApiService.class);
        }
        return apiService;
    }

}
```

ApiService.java

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET("products/3/categories")
    Call<List<Result>> getResponse(@Header("Content-Type") String content_type);
}
```

Result.java

```
public class Result {


    @SerializedName("category_id")
    private String entityId;

    public String getEntityId() {
        return entityId;
    }

    public void setEntityId(String entityId) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
    }

}
```

[Postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8R5u.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880577/how-to-do-a-get-request-using-retrofit2/40880645#40880645

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's the `Accept` header you need to set.  You can also call following when building Retrofit instance: `addHeader("Accept", "application/json")`

Answer (score 0):

create interceptor like this and add it in 
okhttpCLient.addInterceptor(interecptor);

```
Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request newRequest;
            newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
                    .build();

            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    };
```